# (libwebsocket) How to sent a packet on client connection

Tags: c, websocket, libwebsockets

I'm developing a simple websocket server on Linux using libwebsocket lib.
I need to send an init packet on established event for every client connection.
If I use

```
memcpy( p, "init", 4);
lws_write(wsi, p, 4, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
```

in

```
case LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED:
```

I receive the error

```
[2018/07/31 18:50:15:5451] ERR: 
[2018/07/31 18:50:15:5451] ERR: 0000: 81 04 69 6E 69 74         ..init
[2018/07/31 18:50:15:5451] ERR: 
[2018/07/31 18:50:15:5451] ERR: ** 0x564b10ce5170: vh: default, prot: lws-minimal, role ws: Illegal back-to-back write of 6 detected...
```

From the documentation I read that I cannot recall `lws_write` in this phase but  don't understand how to prepare data for the `LWS_CALLBACK_SERVER_WRITEABLE` phase (and then call `lws_callback_on_writable(wsi);`..).

Why the error reports 6 bytes when I lws-write 4 bytes?

Comment: I don't use `libwebsockets` myself, but I imagine the `6` might be related to the additional two byte header that's attached to small messages (less than 127 bytes long)... 2 byte header + 4 byte message => 6 bytes written.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documents](https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-master/html/group__sending-data.html#gafd5fdd285a0e25ba7e3e1051deec1001), `lws_write()` requires that `LWS_PRE` bytes are available before the pointer you pass in to write.

```
char buf[LWS_PRE + 32];                           // buffer of any size plus the LWS_PRE
lws_strncpy(&buf[LWS_PRE], "init", 4);            // use their stncpy to null-terminate
lws_write(wsi, &buf[LWS_PRE], 4, LWS_WRITE_TEXT); // write from your buffer after LWS_PRE bytes.
```